# A construction of Weyl-equivariant maps from the space of regular Cartan triples to the space of tuples of complex polynomials (up to scalar factors)

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group, equivariant, geometric-constructions

Let $G$ be a compact semisimple Lie group and let $T$ be a maximal torus in $G$. On the Lie algebra level, we have a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a (particular) real slice, say $\mathfrak{t}$, of the Cartan subalgebra of the complexification of $\mathfrak{g}$ respectively. We let $W$ denote the Weyl group of $(G, T)$.

Let $\lambda \in \mathfrak{t}^*$ be a weight of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. an element of the weight lattice of $\mathfrak{g}$. If $\Delta$ denotes the set of (non-zero) roots of $(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{t})$, we then have
$$ m_{\alpha}(\lambda) = \langle H_\alpha, \lambda \rangle \in \mathbb{Z} $$
for any root $\alpha \in \Delta$, where $H_\alpha \in \mathfrak{t}$ is the co-root associated to $\alpha$ and $\langle -, - \rangle$ denotes the natural pairing between $\mathfrak{t}$ and its dual space $\mathfrak{t}^*$.

Let $\mathcal{O} = W.\lambda$ denote the Weyl orbit of $\lambda$.

Let $\alpha \in \Delta$ be a root of $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathfrak{t} \otimes \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular Cartan triple (here regular means that $\beta(\mathbf{x})$ is a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for any root $\beta \in \Delta$). We denote the space of regular Cartan triples by $(\mathfrak{t} \otimes \mathbb{R}^3)_0$. We then define
$$ h_{\alpha}(t) = ut - v $$
where $\mathbf{0} \neq (u, v) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ is a choice of Hopf lift of the nonzero vector $\alpha(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Note that $h_{\alpha}(t)$ is defined up to a nonzero complex scalar factor (due to the Hopf lift ambiguity).

Given $\lambda' \in \mathcal{O}$, we define
$$ p_{\lambda'}(t) = \prod_{\alpha \in \Delta} h_{\alpha}(t)^{\operatorname{max}(0, m_{\alpha}(\lambda'))} $$
which is a complex polynomial function of $t$, well defined up to a nonzero complex scalar factor only.

We then define the map
$$F_\mathcal{O}(\mathbf{x}) = (p_{\lambda'}(t) ; \lambda' \in \mathcal{O})$$
from the space $(\mathfrak{t} \otimes \mathbb{R}^3)_0$ into the space of $|\mathcal{O}|$-tuples of complex polynomial functions (each up to a nonzero complex scalar factor only).

Note that the map $F_{\mathcal{O}}$ is Weyl equivariant and also $SU(2)$-equivariant (the latter acts on the $\mathbb{R}^3$ factor of the domain via its adjoint action and acts on the space of complex polynomial functions via its action on the coefficients of each linear factor by its action on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ by Moebius transformations).

Basically, I have this construction (which is published in Exp. Math.) and I am not sure what to do with it. It is definitely inspired by the Atiyah problem on configurations (which it generalizes). My question is whether or not this construction is interesting, and whether it could have any applications. Thoughts and/or comments are welcome!